# Google kubernetes engine node-pool problem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

**When i try to create a node-pool using n2 and e2 machines in google kubernetes engine it shows this error**

> Creation of node-pool with N1 machine type

Create node pool "pool-1" in Kubernetes Engine cluster 
11 minutes ago
Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "N2_CPUS": request requires '2.0' and is short '2.0'. project has a quota of '0.0' with '0.0' available. View and manage quotas at

Create node pool "pool-5" in Kubernetes Engine cluster 
9 minutes ago
Deploy error: Not all instances running in IGM after 14.847846874s. Expect 1. Current errors: [ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS]: Instance 'gxxxxxxxpool-5-5365e95a-xw5r' creation failed: The zone 'projects/xxxx/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. '(resource type:compute)'.

> Creation of node-pool with E2 machine type

**but my quotas are not exceeded.It is possible to create node-pool with N1 type machines.Can anyone help to resolve this issue.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow cannot help you solve this problem.

The problem is that Google Cloud does not have enough resources available to allocate to you.

You have several options:

1. Wait. Resources will eventually become available. This could be minutes or days.
2. Select a different zone or region. Resource usage and availability will vary from zone to zone and region to region.
3. Select a different instance type. Availability varies between instance types.